# pandas: Aggregate on one column and count based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
   fid prefix target_text
0   f1     p1          t1
1   f1     p1          t2
2   f1     p2          t1
3   f1     p2          t2
4   f1     p3          t1
5   f1     p3          t3
6   f1     p3          t4
7   f2     p1          t1
8   f2     p1          t2
9   f2     p2          t2
10  f2     p2          t1
```

If I group them by `fid` and `prefix` and count unique `target_text` I have:

```
>>> num_targets = df.groupby(['fid','prefix'])['target_text'].transform('nunique')

0     2
1     2
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     2
8     2
9     2
10    2
```

Now I want to group them by only 'fid' but in front of it print the number of distinct [`prefix`, `target_text`]

I expect:

```
      num_targets           
f1    7
f2    4
```

However if I gourp the dataframe by `fid`, then how can I count distinct `[prefix, target_text]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need unique per both columns output is different:

```
s = (df['target_text']  + '_' + df['prefix']).groupby(df['fid']).nunique()
print (s)
fid
f1    7
f2    4
dtype: int64
```

---

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(['fid','prefix','target_text'])['fid'].value_counts()
print (s)
f1    7
f2    4
Name: fid, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I modified my question with another sample that your solution apparently fails. For `f2` it must print `4` but it prints `2`. I was concerned about drop_duplicates in your solution.

Comment: @Ahmad - how is count `5` and `4` ? Can you explian more?